# use of Map doesn't cause NPE

Tags: java, dictionary, nullpointerexception

Consider this:

```
public class Model{
    private Map<Vector, Vector> vertices;

    public Model(Vector v){
        vertices.put(v, v);
    }
}
```

I was expecting an NPE since vertices is uninitialized; at least I was expecting an error as Map is abstract and I'm working with an object.
Can somebody shed a light here?

EDIT:

```
public class World{
    public static void init(){
        Model cube = new Model(someVector);
    }
}
```

I have a Main class containing main(); in main() I'm calling `World.init();`

The code is simplified for readability.
EDIT 1:

```
public class Model extends Positionable{
    public static Map<String, Model> map = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Vector3f, Vector3f> vertsAndNormals;
    private Set<Face> faces;

    public Model(String name_, Map<Vector3f, Vector3f> vertsAndNormals_){
        super(); // \!/ passing `this`; may not have been entirely initialized
        vertsAndNormals = new HashMap<>(vertsAndNormals_);
        map.put(name_, this);
        }
    public Model(String name_, Set<Vector3f> vertices_){
        super(); // \!/ passing `this`; may not have been entirely initialized

        for(Vector3f vertex : vertices_)
            vertsAndNormals.put(vertex, new Vector3f(0, 0, 0)); // \!/ why does this NOT cause an NPE?

        map.put(name_, this);
        }
    public Model(String name_){
        this(name_, new HashMap<Vector3f, Vector3f>());
        }
    }
```

and where I call:

```
public class World{
    public static Set<Model> modelsInWorld = new HashSet<>();

    public static void init(){
        Model cube = new Model("gugu");
        }
    }
```

In main():

```
World.init();
```

EDIT 2:

```
public abstract class Positionable{
    public static Set<Positionable> set = new HashSet<>(); 

    public float x = 0;
    public float y = 0;
    public float z = 0;
    public float xRol = 0;
    public float yPit = 0;
    public float zYaw = 0;

    public Positionable(){
        set.add(this);
        }
}
```

Comment: So you're saying you didn't get a `NPE` there? That shouldn't be the case with current code. Are you sure you didn't initialize the map elsewhere?

Comment: How do you call that class?

Comment: This will cause an NPE at runtime (not at compile time, if that's what you were expecting).

Comment: Where is the code that you are running which you expect to throw? It won't throw just at compile time.

Comment: Please provide the entire code, as this small snippet will cause a NPE :-)

Comment: At what time are you expecting the exception, compile or runtime ?

Comment: *The code is simplified for readability.*: and by simplifying it, you hide the part which causes the NPE not to happen. Post compilable code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: I'm running it, it displays just fine; no error thrown.

Comment: You're not running the code that you posted, which doesn't even compile. You're running code that we can't see because you haven't posted it.

Comment: @JB there's a lot of dependability (many classes/files) and I'm not sure it wouldn't cause a lot of clutter. But if you think it's necessary, I'll post it.

Comment: Post a compilable example that reproduces the problem. Not all of your code.

Comment: It's difficult with the imports :D lwjgl libraries are needed but one can replace with other types as necessary.

Comment: What exactly do I have to do? I always get negatives on my questions. What did I do wrong? I'll post a link with my entire project!!

Comment: I'm using NetBeans 7.4; here it is:http://www.mediafire.com/download/nh3otrichxeh6aq/LIME.zip EDIT: should the compiler complain about references, all the needed libs are in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually calling the constructor that has the line you're concerned about. You call the constructor that takes a `String`, which forwards to the constructor that takes a `String` and a `Map`. The constructor that takes a `Set` will cause an NPE at runtime.

Comment: I really should take a coffee or any kind of brake :)

Comment: Thanks. And I thank everybody who took the time to analyze the code. The first constructor was the one with name; calling this one I set in my mind a "reference" to this constructor as being called. I edited to accept a Set and I changed back my mind and re-added the simple constructor afterwards but forgot to edit the "reference" in my head...